# How to select a specific application window using an Apple Script?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I have Logic Pro X running on multiple monitors. Logic can have multiple windows open at once running different things, which I have on each monitor. I am trying to write an apple script to "enable patch merging" in the Logic window in my second monitor. The code I have to do this is as follows:

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of ¬
            window 1 of application process "Logic Pro X"
end ignoring

delay 0.1
do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"
    run
    delay 0.2
    tell application process "Logic Pro X"
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            menu item "Enable Patch Merging" of ¬
            menu 1 of pop up button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Sends" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Audio Effects" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

However, this only works if I have this second window in my second display SELECTED. I usually have the Logic window in my primary display selected. When I run the apple script with any other window selected, I get this error:

> System Events got an error: Can’t get group 2 of window 1 of application process "Logic Pro X". Invalid index.

How can I have the script select the Logic window in question before running this task? It seems to me this is the only workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Before the other day I had not touched **Logic Pro** and downloaded the _trial_ to answer your other question and why I said "There is also only one **Logic Pro** _window_ opened.". --- I do not know if this is a limitation of the _trial_, but it only allows one **Project** to be opened at a time, although it can have multiple _windows_ of the same **Project**. The issues as I see them are: 1. **Logic Pro** sans `renderPreview`, the only item in its **AppleScript** _dictionary_ and some basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** _commands_, e.g., `quit`, it is not **AppleScript** _scriptable_ Cont'd...

Comment: Cont'd... unless using **UI Scripting** with **System Events** and its _application process_. --- 2. The _properties_ of its _windows_ do not expose an `id` _property_ thus making it difficult to distinguish one _window_ from another. --- 3. **UI Scripting** is _kludgy_, prone to failure for a number of reasons, and really should be avoided unless there is no other way to achieve the goal. For example, with two _windows_ opened `group 2` becomes `group 3` in the other _window_. --- 4. After further examination of the situation I'm not going to waste any more time on this, sorry.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes your help on the previous question was extremely helpful! I noticed you hadn't replied to my comment so assumed you may be too busy so no worries at all! I understand the dilemma -- hence why I was wondering if more simply there was just a way to command a series of "clicks" to click on the desired second monitor than through UI Scripting. I imagine though that this is not possible?

Comment: RE: "I imagine though that this is not possible?" -- Generally speaking it _can_ be done. Have a look at: [**cliclick**](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick)

Comment: @user3439894 Darn... I'm still on OSX 10.14 so I guess that option is a no-go for me as well. Too bad I can't seem to get this to work at all...

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you again, I've perused the page but I really do not understand how clickclick works or if/how it can work into an apple script, as well as anything regarding multiple displays. Is there a guide somewhere that explains how I can use clickclick to achieve what I want (a series of clicks occurring on a certain display, to be triggered by a key command?) Also, what is the "MD5" text in your most recent comment used for?